# Get Controller Action based on Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

If I have the following controller:

```
public class RetrievalController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/User")]
    public HttpResponseMessage RetrieveSomethingKthx()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

Is there a way early on (such as in OWIN) to read the path.  E.G.: `Request.Path == "http://www.website.com/api/User"` and therefore get Reflection Information about that method?

Note that I am not relying on the Route to have the Controller Name or "Action" Name necessarily.  I assume something lives in the Web API Routing to pull method info based on the Route.